# Reuse existing QDirIterator in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, destroy, reusability

I use multiple `QDirIterator`s in a single scope of a Qt 5 project. They typically look like this:

```
QDirIterator i(QDir::currentPath(), QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    doSomething();
};
```

Now I use multiple objects all with theirs own names (`i0`, `i1`, `i2` etc.), and I wonder how can I use just one name across the project, `i` in this example? How should I decommission existing `QDirIterator` to reuse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ allows you to introduce a new scope anywhere you need, for example:

```
{
  QDirIterator i(path1, QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    doSomething();
  };
}
{
  QDirIterator i(path2, QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    doSomething();
  };
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks! This is a best practice to reuse identificators?

Comment: It depends on context. Generally, scope of any variable should not be bigger than it needs to be. In some cases it may be better to move repeated parts to a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a forward sequential iterator adapter to `QDirIterator`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/dir-iterator-39133673
#include <QtCore>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

class QDir_iterator : public
        boost::iterator_facade<QDir_iterator, QString,
        boost::forward_traversal_tag, QString>
{
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    boost::optional<QDirIterator &> it;
    bool equal(const QDir_iterator & other) const {
        return **this == *other;
    }
    QString dereference() const {
        return it != boost::none ? it->filePath() : QString{};
    }
    void increment() {
        it->next();
    }
public:
    QDir_iterator() = default;
    QDir_iterator(QDirIterator & dir) : it{dir} {
        it->next();
    }
};

QDir_iterator begin(QDirIterator & dir) { return QDir_iterator{dir}; }
QDir_iterator end(QDirIterator &) { return QDir_iterator{}; }
```

The adapter is usable on a `QDirIterator`, thus you can pass a `QDirIterator` directly to a range-for:

```
void test1() {
    auto curr = QDir::current();
    auto entries = curr.entryList();
    int i = 0;
    for (auto dir : QDirIterator{curr}) ++i;
    Q_ASSERT(i == entries.count());
}
```

You can pass any necessary flags or filters to `QDirIterator`, of course. The adapter will follow them.

If you're allergic to Boost, you could factor out iterating a directory to "save" having to deal with a braced scope:

```
template <typename F>
void iterate(QDirIterator && it, F && fun) {
     while (it.hasNext())
        fun(it.next());
}
```

Iteration uses a temporary iterator - uniform initialization makes it quite painless:

```
void test2() {
    auto curr = QDir::current();
    auto entries = curr.entryList();
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    iterate({curr}, [&](const QString &){ ++i; });
    Q_ASSERT(entries.length() == i);
    iterate({curr}, [&](const QString &){ ++j; });
    Q_ASSERT(entries.length() == j);
}
```